# How to remove all the apt-get packages and updates since installation in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, operating-systems, updates

Iam working on a new project and i some what messed things up in the operating system and i **unnecessarily installed and updates some packages**.So i cant figure out which packages i installed,so i have option of doing a fresh install of Operating system or ***just to remove all (including every update i ever have done since i installed) packages.***

---

Is there any command i can use to completely remove every package which is either broken or damaged.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below command to remove broken packages in ubuntu.

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name`

after removing package update your system with command

`sudo apt-get update`